User registration failed in NodeJS
I am performing user registration process in NodeJS. The problem is, when i test my /register endpoint with postman, the user details gets added to my mongodb database. But when i open the registration form and fill in the details and submit, it shows me registration failed. I don't know what else i might be doing wrong.
Backend logic:
import express from 'express';
import mongoose from 'mongoose';
import cors from 'cors';
import bcrypt from 'bcrypt'; // For password hashing

//connecting to
mongoose.connect("mongodb://0.0.0.0:27017/myDatabase");

const app = express();
//This is our Middleware 
app.use(express.json());
app.use(cors({
    origin: 'http://192.168.222.48:8080',
    methods: 'GET,POST', 
    credentials: true 
}));

const userSchema = new mongoose.Schema({
    firstname: { type: String, required: true },
    lastname: { type: String, required: true},
    email: { type: String, required: true, unique: true},
    telephone: { type: Number, required: true, unique: true},
    password: {
        type: String,
        required: true,
        minlength: 8, // Enforce a minimum password length
        validate: {
          validator: function(password) {
            const hasUpperCase = /[A-Z]/.test(password);
            const hasLowerCase = /[a-z]/.test(password);
            const hasNumbers = /\d/.test(password);
            return hasUpperCase && hasLowerCase && hasNumbers;
          },
          message: 'Password must contain a mix of uppercase letters, lowercase letters, and numbers.'
        }}
});

const User = mongoose.model('User', userSchema);

app.post('/register', async (req, res) => {
    const { firstname, lastname, email, telephone, password } = req.body;

    try {
        // Check if a user with the same email or telephone already exists
        console.log(req.body)
        const existingUser = await User.findOne({ $or: [{ email }, { telephone }] });

        if (existingUser) {
            return res.status(400).json({ message: 'User with this email or telephone already exists' });
        }

        // Hash password
        const hashedPassword = await bcrypt.hash(password, 10);

        // Create user
        const user = new User({ firstname, lastname, email, telephone, password: hashedPassword });
        await user.save();
        res.json({ message: 'User registered successfully' });
    } catch (err) {
        console.error('Error registering user:', err);
        res.status(500).json({ message: 'Error registering user' });
    }

});

app.get('/api/users/:userId', async (req, res) => {
    const userId = req.params.userId;

     const user = await User.findById(userId);


    if (user) {
        res.json (user);
    } else {
        res.status(404).json({error: 'user not found'});
    }
});

app.listen(3000, () => {
    console.log('Server listening on port 3000');
});


Frontend formData handling:

  const [formData, setFormData] = useState({
    firstname: '',
    lastname: '',
    email: '',
    telephone: '',
    password: '',
  });

  const handleInputChange = (event) => {
    const { name, value } = event.target;
    setFormData((prevData) => ({
      ...prevData,
      [name]: value,
    }));
  };

const handleSubmit = async (event) => {
    event.preventDefault();
    console.log(formData);

    try {
        const response = await fetch('http://localhost:3000/register', {
          method: 'POST',
          headers: {
              'Content-Type': 'application/json'
          },
          body: JSON.stringify({
                firstname: formData.firstname,
                lastname: formData.lastname,
                email: formData.email,
                telephone: formData.telephone,
                password: formData.password
           
          })
          
      });

        if (response.ok) {
            console.log('User registered successfully');
        } else {
            console.error('Failed to register user');
        }
    } catch (error) {
        console.error('Error:', error);
    }
};

This is my browser console:  

Are you getting any error logs on your backend? Your server is returning status 500 so I'd expect it to be logging out the issue it's running into
